# How to convert require to import in es6 syntax

Tags: reactjs, npm, fonts

I have this [typeface source sans pro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeface-source-sans-pro).

Currently syntax is `require('typeface-source-sans-pro')`

I want to convert it to es6 syntax using `import`.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: ... why? Why not have that asset in your static assets folder, and then point to that in your `@font-face` CSS? Never bundle static assets, all that does is make it much, much harder for browsers to properly cache things that will almost never change, and makes your users redownload files they would have otherwise not needed to redownload.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import 'typeface-source-sans-pro/index.css'
```